# What are CSS hooks and what are very common CSS hooks?

Tags: css

I have been introduced to the term CSS hooks but I am not very clear on that. Could you give me some ideas?

- what are CSS hooks ?
- what are the most common hooks?
- what are the best practices for using CSS hooks?

Any kind of example and relevant links are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Could you elaborate?

CSS Hooks are generally considered to be classes or ID's placed in the HTML to allow a backend or server side language to interact with these client side 'hooks'

Comment: I am not clear thats why I asked ? :) As far I know hooks are common css classes,ids that can be used in various scenarios. Say you have a promo in your site. Then if you have some predefined css hooks you just add the class name in the html elements and you will get the style. I want to provide such few common css hooks for my customers.

Comment: What you are describing is just fundamental CSS. Setting styles on a  class/id and applying this to a html element will give it that style. I think classing this as a hook is using the wrong terminology and will only confuse things.                             If you were setting these classes/id's for the benefit of being able to target a specific area of your markup with say jQuery, then it would be more appropriate to use the term hook

Answer (score 3):

> What is CSS Hooks?

CSS Hooks is a simple mechanism, which defines a way for your element to retrieve its styles from a third source.

> What are the common hooks?

There are not any. Variation lies in your imagination.

> What are the best practices to use CSS Hooks?

Look into [JQuery.cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/).

Answer (score 0):

1. What are CSS hooks?

A hook allows you to tap into a CSS feature that is normally inaccessible within inline styles. The canonical first example is the `:hover` pseudo-class; but the possibilities include the full range of pseudo-classes, media queries, container queries, and even custom selectors.

You can find the documentation at [css-hooks.com](https://css-hooks.com).

2. What are the most common hooks?

The most commonly-used hooks include `hover`, `focus`, `active`, and `disabled`. But CSS Hooks ships with ~30 "recommended" hooks, and you can extend or replace this list with your own custom hooks.

3. What are the best practices for using CSS hooks?

CSS Hooks simply extends the capabilities of native inline styles, so all of the same "best practices" would apply. The main thing to remember is that, although inline styles are extremely practical and convenient, you should still follow the DRY principle. Use HTML templating via React, Solid.js, or another supported framework.